# UITableView doesn't show images

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

It appears my tableview delegate won't show my image at all. The image shows fine on my UIImageView that I added to my view controller. I am using the table view from interface builder if this bit of information helps.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myimage];

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the delegate and data source via `interface builder`, Or in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
//...
}
```

Also, make sure that the `myImage` object is not `nil`

If i can remember correctly, `default` style has an imageView property. Try:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got this error. -[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81ec820

Comment: make sure you are calling the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method. And return the number of objects you have in your array.

Comment: `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];` is the right way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate and datasource in your viewDidLoad method and within your .h file in stead of the delegate method of the tableview itself.

EDIT:

Also make sure that all your delegates methods are added

Those delegates are:

```
// Return the number of sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Return the number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

//filling of tableview
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

//pressing of a row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got this error  -[ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x81ec820